# Prestashop 1.7 /admin error 500

Tags: prestashop, admin, prestashop-1.7

I just installed PrestaShop 1.7.2.0 and I'm getting error 500 when I'm trying to access */admin*.
My admin folder on FTP is renamed to *admin[random_string]* (how? why?). Frontend seems to be working ok.

When I remove */admin/.htaccess* I get 404, when I put it back, I get 500. I did change anything inside of it.

What could be a problem?

Comment: Any help pls? Will appreciate anything

Comment: a) have you deleted the `install` folder (not sure right now if this is still necessary with 1.7.x)?

b) if that doesn't work / is not needed please look at the contents of the apache logs *edit: just read your comment to the first answer* - you shoudl be able to find said log in `/hosting/www/[your_site]/www/error.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the installation if you have not renamed the admin folder PrestaShop does it for you, for security reason. So in your case the folder was renamed as `admin[random string]`, if you want you can rename it as you want.

Obviously now to access to the backoffice you have to use the 'new' path, for example in your case, `http://www.myshop.com/admin[random string]/` and **not** `http://www.myshop.com/admin/`

Comment: Well, the same result (error 500) I get even accessing http://www.myshop.com/admin881ooxfdf/

Comment: Have you activated the debug mode?

Comment: If you think `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`, yes, but still I see just error 500 :|

Comment: Yes, have you activated the display errors and changed the error level to display on your hosting?

Comment: I have this in my .user.ini file: `log_errors = 1
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
error_log = /hosting/www/sperkovani.cz/www/error.log
`When I try to divide by zero in a script not related to Prestashop, I get an error record. But this error 500 of prestashop administration is not writing to log...

Comment: Try this settings:
`display_errors = On`
`error_reporting = 32759`

Comment: I changed the file to `log_errors = 1
display_errors = On
error_reporting = 32759`
but with no change of result

Comment: Ok, renaming .htaccess in admin folder helped. Should I keep it disabled?

Comment: Can you post, in the question, the content of the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is running Windows, comment this two rules under admin[random_string]/.htaccess

```
# If the URL is a legacy on index.php?controller=..., do not rewrite (let the legacy take it)
     RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)controller=|(^|&)tab=
     RewriteRule .* - [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to increase memory_limit to 512M and max_execution_time to 300 in php.ini

```
    memory_limit=512M
    max_execution_time=300
```